# Function running unnecessarily

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs, subscribe

I have code like this

```
this.service.function().subscribe(data :any) => {
   this.array = data
   this.flat(this.array)
});
```

My problem is the `flat` function is running unnecessarily several times. I only want to this to run when `this.array` got some values.

How do I deal with this? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `filter` operator to check whether data has values or not (`data.length` check). It will take of only run the subscription if array contains values.

```
import { filter } from 'rxjs/operators'

this.service.function().pipe(
   filter(d => d.length)
).subscribe(data => {
   this.array = data
   this.flat(this.array)
});
```

Comment: I think this might be it. I will do this and report back.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
this.service.function().subscribe(data => {
this.array = data
if (data?.length > 0) {
  this.flat(this.array)
}
}
);
```

Comment: Thats simple enough. Thanks

Comment: I tried this but the function wouldnt run at all, I want to run the function WHEN this.array get the values.

Comment: This will only run when your subscribe emits a value. That is when: data is not null, undefined or []

Comment: Hi, sorry for late replys, I am getting syntax errors when I do this specifically on data?.length > 0). Error is: Expression expected. This is appearing near ?.